# How to show timing details with HTTPie

Tags: httpie

This [blog post](https://blog.josephscott.org/2011/10/14/timing-details-with-curl/) shows that you can show timing details, e.g:

```
$ curl -w "@curl_format.txt" -o /dev/null -s https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments
     time_namelookup:  0.001478s
        time_connect:  0.010429s
     time_appconnect:  0.028095s
    time_pretransfer:  0.028209s
       time_redirect:  0.000000s
  time_starttransfer:  0.046213s
                     ----------
          time_total:  0.065945s
```

I think HTTPie is more user friendly, though. Is there a way to achieve similar thing on HTTPie?

Answer (score 4):

HTTPie 3.0.0 has it: https://httpie.io/docs/cli/response-meta

```
$ http google.com --meta
Elapsed time: 0.080979083s
```

You can upgrade via:

```
pip install httpie --upgrade
```

(depending on your system, you might need `sudo` in front of the command ... and it might be `pip3` on your system)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, that is the most awaited feature, see [issue #243](https://github.com/httpie/httpie/issues/243). It is not yet available as of HTTPie 2.6.0.